Neo4j consistency check issue after upgrading to Neo4j 4
I am currently upgrading from Neo4j 3.5.35 to 4.0.12 (community edition) and I'm experiencing problems with the consistency check of our backups created using neo4j-admin dump. Neo4j is running as a service in Docker Swarm.
The backup and consistency check is done in a Jenkins pipeline by running a shell script with the following steps:

Scale the Neo4j service to 0, i.e. shutdown Neo4j.
Start a new Neo4j container and run neo4j-admin dump to create a dump file.
Start a new custom container based on Neo4j that uses neo4j-admin load to load the dump file created in the previous step, and then do the consistency check using neo4j-admin check-consistency.

This worked well with Neo4j 3.5.35, but with Neo4j 4.0.12 I get the following error:
org.neo4j.cli.CommandFailedException: Active logical log detected, this might be a source of inconsistencies.
Please recover database before running the consistency check.
To perform recovery please start database and perform clean shutdown.
        at org.neo4j.consistency.CheckConsistencyCommand.checkDbState(CheckConsistencyCommand.java:181)
        at org.neo4j.consistency.CheckConsistencyCommand.execute(CheckConsistencyCommand.java:129)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:59)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:29)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1743)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:145)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2101)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2068)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:1935)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1864)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:87)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:65)

Not sure how to do a clean shutdown other than scaling the Docker service to 0, the STOP DATABASE command does not seem to be available in community edition.
The content of the /data/databases/graph.db folder looks like this:
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         0 Apr  8 14:21 database_lock
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root      4096 Apr  8 14:21 index
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8192 Apr  8 14:21 neostore
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     46688 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.counts.db.a
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     46688 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.counts.db.b
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18776064 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.labelscanstore.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8190 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.labeltokenstore.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8192 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10835370 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.nodestore.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    111793 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.nodestore.db.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10190848 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.nodestore.db.labels
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      1409 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.nodestore.db.labels.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 139951327 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  30515200 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       289 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    435785 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8190 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.index
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.index.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8192 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   1523712 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.strings
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       785 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.propertystore.db.strings.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    106275 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       273 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  31571040 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.relationshipstore.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    112545 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.relationshipstore.db.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8190 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8192 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names.id
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8192 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.schemastore.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr  8 14:21 neostore.schemastore.db.id
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root      4096 Apr  8 14:21 schema

Any hints on this are very much appreciated.

I managed to resolve this issue by invoking the consistency checker with the --database option instead of --backup.
With Neo4j 3.5.35, I was using
neo4j-admin check-consistency --backup=/data/databases/graph.db

where /data/databases/graph.db is the directory to which the dump to check has been loaded.
With Neo4j 4.0, I am using
neo4j-admin check-consistency --database=graph.db

in the root directory of the container and everything works perfectly.
